# Terminal unresponsive when attempting to deploy

Tags: nginx, deployment, terminal, zsh, digital-ocean

So I'm using the following technologies:

Digital Ocean
Name Cheap
zsh terminal on mac

I have an app that I have successfully deployed for practice about ten times now and all of a sudden my terminal is being highly unresponsive and not allowing me to do any of my commands.

I'm supposed to set up a new subdomain on digital ocean, and then git clone my ssh key into a new directory in my terminal that relates to the new subdomain I created.

That is all going fine. Going into nvim and putting in my env, secret and port is also okay but again that lags like crazy. When i do npm i, I get the message "killed". pm2 logs and pm2 start commands either don't work or take forever to come up. Getting to ranger and navigating to nginx is possible but lags and the last time i pulled it up, the whole window didn't even render and I wasn't able to put in my new server block.

On the few occassions I put in my server block and run nginx -t for the test, I DO have successful test runs, but then when i run `certbot --nginx`, it either freezes or it all goes awry and can't access the new subdomain.

I tried restarting my computer, starting over with new subdomains, and still nothing has worked. I'm wary to try removing anything since I'm still a beginner with this and do not want to dig myself into a deeper hole. Looking for suggestions in how to possibly speed up my terminal or perhaps find a way around this. Maybe make a new parent directory to work from? However our instructor was clear with us saying we can have virtually infinite subdomains under one domain, so I am genuinely at a loss for answers and at the same time do not want to try something i don't fully understand.